# Jquery u-i sortable scrolls to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a huge issue with my ui-sortable.

If i have a small list (as the one in the example on their website: [jquery sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/))

Then there is no Issue.

However if the list gets big long enough and the user would have to scroll to see the total list then when ever i try to drag an element it automaticly scrolls to the bottom and i have a hard time getting it up again.

Every time i attempt to scroll up it scrolls down seconds later. So my question is has anyone tried this before and know a fix for it? ( i know there wasnt much code however if you really need code to solve this problem il gladly provide what i have)

The element im dragging:

```
<ul  class="list-group gutter list-group-lg list-group-sp" ui-sortable="sortable" ng-model="academyModules">
    <li class="list-group-item module"  style="padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px; display: block" ng-repeat="module in academyModules" draggable="true">
        <div class="clear" ng-if="module.module.module_type_id != null">
            <span class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-sort text-muted fa m-r-sm"></i> </span>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-10">
                <button class="btn btn-s-xs btn-rounded m-r-lg" ng-class="module.module_type.color || module.module.module_type.color"
                        style="padding:  2px 10px; min-width: 90px;">{{module.module_type.name || module.module.module_type.name}}
                </button>
                <span class="text text-muted" translate="TERMS.MODULE"></span>
            </div>
            <span class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-md pull-right no-padder" ng-really-message="{{ 'ACADEMY.EDIT.MODULES.DELETE_WARNING' | translate }}" tooltip="{{ 'TOOLTIP.DELETE' | translate }}" ng-really-click="deleteModule($index, module);">
                    <i class="fa fa-times text-danger text"></i></a>
            </span>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-11">
                <div class="input-group m-b">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="changeModule(module)" data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#modal_select_module" style="font-size: 10px;"
                                type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span translate="ACADEMY.EDIT.MODULES.CHANGE_MODULE"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /btn-group -->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="{{module.module.name}}" style="height: 27px" disabled="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear" ng-if="module.module.module_type_id == null">
            <span class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-sort text-muted fa m-r-sm"></i> </span>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-10">
                <button class="btn btn-s-xs btn-rounded m-r-lg bg-grey"
                        style="padding:  2px 10px; min-width: 90px;" translate="TERMS.COURSE">
                </button>
                <span class="text text-muted" translate="TERMS.COURSE"></span>
            </div>
            <span class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-md pull-right no-padder" title="" ng-really-message="{{ 'ACADEMY.EDIT.COURSES.DELETE_WARNING' | translate }}" tooltip="{{ 'TOOLTIP.DELETE' | translate }}" ng-really-click="deleteCourse($index, module);"><i
                        class="fa fa-times text-danger text"></i></a>
            </span>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-11">
                <div class="input-group m-b">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="changeCourse(module)" data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#modal_select_module" style="font-size: 10px;"
                                type="button"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i><span translate="ACADEMY.EDIT.COURSES.EDIT"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /btn-group -->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="{{module.name}}" style="height: 27px" disabled="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Please provide a working jFiddle of this situation. Only HTML will make it difficult to help you out.

Comment: You could take a look at this. The ui has an option who deals with the scroll:  https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-scrollSensitivity

Comment: @Mouser Sadly im not very good at fiddles but something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/rbkLmoLv/1/